# Pass static value to a field in Solr DIH indexing

Tags: solr, solrcloud

For Solr 8, I am using DIH to index the documents into Solr. Is there any way to pass a static value for particular field without having to get it from the query I'm doing for fetching data?

Comment: it can be added as select 1 as id, 'Abhijit' as name from dual...

Comment: also please share what you have done till now and where exactly you are stuck...